# An Ampersand (&) before a function means?

Tags: php

I know `&` is used to create references.

But I wonder what having a `&` before a function name means:

```
function &DB($params = '', $active_record_override = FALSE) { // code }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It returns the result by reference. [See the manual entry for it here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php).